# Converting a string in to offset-aware datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, datetimeoffset

I wanted to create a string time in to offset-aware timezone for comparing with another offset-aware datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import parser
from dateutil.tz import gettz

today = datetime.now(gettz())  # creating a offset-aware timezone, I wanted to create manual string time also in this format

new_date = parser.parse('Apr 1 2014')  # I wanted this output to be converted into offset-aware timezone
```

output of today variable is = 2014-04-30 07:54:26.500678+05:30
output of new_date variable is = 2014-04-01 00:00:00 ( need to convert this into above format )

any other method for converting this ?

Comment: `new_date = new_date.replace(tzinfo=gettz())`

Comment: WoW, that works, Thanks Desired Login :)